# Would there be any mass extinction should the polarity of Earth magnetic field flips at 1 GHz?

Tags: earth, survival, electromagnetism, extinction

If the polarity of our Earth magnetic field were to flip (oscillate) at around 1 GHz or 1 billion cycles per second, would it spell disaster to fauna and flora that depends on it for navigation like hunting for found or in search of potential mates? Would such an event throw us (the modern human civilization) back a few decades? I'm imagining what the needle inside the compass is doing...

Comment: Water magnetic resonance is 2.45 GHz, so you are kinda close to making Earth a giant microwave. By the way, where is this energy supposed to come from? And for needle in compass, this would do nothing, it is way too heavy to react to 1 GHz radio wave.

Comment: You just ran into the ["Hi, I have a High-Concept"](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-i-have-a-high-concept-please-do-my-work-for-me-questions) trap. Apart from that: what @Mołot just said... flipping does not happen by itself. It takes **enormous** amount of energy to reverse the processes that cause the magnetic field. Where is that coming from?

Comment: Wanting to know where the energy to cause the geomagnetic field to oscillate at GHz comes from is irrelevant to the OP's actual question. It deals with three related areas of potential impact. Perhaps it might be restricted further, that's often according to taste.

Comment: You know that that's kinda how an electric stove works, right?

Comment: More to the point, just _what_ is being oscillated to create a 1 GHz oscillation in the Earth's magnetic field? It isn't as though there's a giant bar magnet between the poles

Comment: You need to narrow it down. Chose between animals or humans. You can only save one. Chose wisely.

Comment: @nzaman, MichaelK, Molot... the mechanics behind the flip is ***irrelevant***.  This site is about science fiction, not simply science fact.  Backstory justification is *always* the OP's problem.  He didn't even include the [tag:science-based] tag.  Please stop holding him to a non-existent standard.

Comment: @JBH: So we can answer that magically nobody is affected? We have to know the context in which the question is asked before we can answer. Whether it was the Valar that did it, or a scientific basis changes the answer. If his Earth does have a bar magnet between the poles, or if somehow molten metals in the core suddenly decide to rotate differently, we need to know why. It isn't something that the OP can expect to know the context of.

Comment: @nzaman I understand that you could be benefitted by knowing that information, but no, you do not need to know that to answer the question.  It's no different than asking given X amount of light what will happen to human skin?  And you insist on knowing whether it's natural or artificial light when you don't actually need to know.  It's a bad habit on this site to demand to know the cause of the cause rather than simply focusing on the effect.

Comment: @JBH: I would like to know if the light is normal light, X-rays or microwave. The intensity alone tells me nothing. To use the question at hand, let's say the OP tells me that his magnetic field is caused by metallic dragons flying around inside a hollow earth, and the flux is due to one of them dying and throwing the flight into disarray. That tells me that the background is high fantasy and I can use that to answer. If he tells me it's pure science, I'd tell him it isn't possible. I know from the tags that it isn't <science based>, but how much fantasy am I allowed?

Comment: @nzaman, what fantasy do you need?  A planetary-strength magnetic field is switching poles at 1Ghz.  What is the effect on animals and humans?  Again, you're focusing on the cause of the cause as if it's important.  It's not.  Let the OP worry about the backstory and just answer the question.  The effects of a magnetic field on biology won't change due to the source of the field's oscillations.  (Thank goodness or all scientific tests based on simplified models would be false.)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming a uncaring god was fiddling with the developer settings in Sid Moider's Earth™ III:

Electronics will catch fire first, life would be extinct within hours and the oceans will boil soon enough. Mołot is right: a GHz turns the earth into a giant microwave. All that energy will need to dissipate somehow and the easiest thing will be all the highly conductive things on the surface (also known as "life").

I'm not good enough with physics to calculate this right now, too many variables involved. It seems that even at a Ghz the power would be several orders of magnitude smaller than a microwave but that will still boil everything within days.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_heating for the mechanism
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/339481/how-strong-is-the-electrical-field-inside-a-microwave-oven for another stackexchanger who did a lot of calculations.

Answer (score 1):

At current 3 Hz fluctuation (which is only a percent of field magnitude, and you don't need to actually flip poles to cause power output - you need magnitude change!) power of field is in reality measured by nanowatts per square meter. It scales up with square of amplitude and proportional to e in power of frequency. Level of microwave power output on surface would become watts, which is dangerous even if not on level of microwave oven, but that's on surface! Surface is not where planet's field is the strongest!

Magnetic field is what creates radiation belt and hold ionosphere in grip of planet. Planet would be baked by sun radiation bursts during pole change and world-wide electric storms, everything manmade on orbit would be irradiated and flung away/slammed by torn protuberances of ionosphere.

Even just changeing poles once is exinction event, because it provides a period of intermediate absense of defense. Turning planet into what amounts to pulsar star signs extinction event on scale of solar system